# ffmpeg memory increase

Tags: c++, qt, memory, ffmpeg, ram

Well, I'm working with ffmpeg, When I execute it, it runs a video example, well, the memory start to increase, a simple small video takes 800MB in RAM, meanwhile Windows Media Player just takes 50MB for run that file, I don't know what's happening, here is the loop, the problems comes from here (I think...)

```
while(av_read_frame(formatContext,&framepacket)>= 0){
    pausecontrol.lock();


    if(framepacket.stream_index==gotVideoCodec){
        int framereaded;

        avcodec_decode_video2(videoCodecContext,videoFrame,&framereaded,&framepacket);

        if(framereaded){

            struct SwsContext *ctx = sws_getContext(videoCodecContext->width, videoCodecContext->height, videoCodecContext->pix_fmt, showinWidget->width(),
            showinWidget->height(), PIX_FMT_RGB24, SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            sws_scale(ctx,videoFrame->data,videoFrame->linesize,0,videoCodecContext->height,videoFrame->data,videoFrame->linesize);
            memset(&framecapsule,0,sizeof(QImage));
            framecapsule=QImage(showinWidget->width(),showinWidget->height(),QImage::Format_RGB888);
            for(int y=0;y<showinWidget->height();y++){
                memcpy(framecapsule.scanLine(y),videoFrame->data[0]+y*videoFrame->linesize[0],showinWidget->width()*3);
            }
            emit newFrameReady();
        }
    }
    if(framepacket.stream_index==gotAudioCodec){
        // Audio? Ok
    }
    pausecontrol.unlock();
    av_free_packet(&framepacket);
}
```

Oh, I'm using QT too, but the converstion between  AVFrame-QImage it's not the problem.

Comment: Make sure you aren't compiling in debug mode.

Comment: Tested it at release mode, now, it wasting me 400MB of RAM

Comment: You probably have a memory leak in your code. Try playing the video with ffplay, if it doesn't go to 400 RAM, the problem is in your code, not in ffmpeg.

Comment: It's a problem with my code.... How do you recommend me to play an avi file? Ffplay only takes 17 MB of ram to play it.... :S

Comment: A memory leak! I was saving the image inside that framecapsule, framecapsule=QImage(.....), well, the problem was, that I was creating the new image inside this new variable, memset did not work, so the last image created was inside the memory, losing all the control of it.... Thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks! Using a different way, now my app it's just wasting me 10MB for playing that file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I have already solved it (thanks to Satuon)....

The problem was, that I was creating the new image inside the variable 'framecapsule' variable, memset did not work, so the last image created was inside the memory, losing all the control of it....

A memory leak! Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 4):

You must create the `SwsContext` once, rather than creating it in loop. At the end, you have to free the context by calling `sws_freeContext`

```
struct SwsContext *ctx = sws_getContext(videoCodecContext->width, videoCodecContext->height, videoCodecContext->pix_fmt, showinWidget->width(),
 showinWidget->height(), PIX_FMT_RGB24, SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);

 while(av_read_frame(formatContext,&framepacket)>= 0)
 {
   /// .....
 }

sws_freeContext(ctx);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have no idea of that function called sws_freeContext!